Instancing subclasses programmatically
How would one instance a scene that is defined as a subclass, where the superclass's .tscn would be shared between all subclasses?
For a card-battler project, I am trying to make my codebase more extendable with classes. I have a script defining the class EnemyBase, with separate scripts for EnemyTypeA, EnemyTypeB, etc. I am imagining a situation where I only need a single .tscn file, and I can somehow assign the correct class to the scene for getting its logic. I want this so that I could, in theory, create as many enemy types as I want, and have just as easy of a time maintaining the codebase, as the common functions would only be written once (in the superclass).
Currently, the only methods I have found to work are (A) creating a separate .tscn file per subclass, and (B) using "pseudo" classes, instead of having subclasses at all, by having an enum variable in the class def holding names of various "subclasses", and having match statements in all of the functions to define different functionality for the different "classes". I believe neither of these are the solution because (A) is essentially having many completely separately defined scenes, and (B) makes that one script very long and unreadable (but seems like the better of the two).
This seems like a pretty obvious/common want, so I imagine there is a neat way to do this. If there is another way of organizing the scenes besides class/subclass's, I'd love to hear about that as well. Thanks.

For anyone wondering in the future, I have found an acceptable solution to this issue (working in Godot 4.+).
This solution hinges on the fact that a scene's script is a parameter which can be changed programmatically. So, a "shared" scene can be created with whatever nodes all of the subclasses will contain. For example, in this case of enemy variations, I could have the scene baseEnemy.tscn contain things like a Label node containing its name, a ProgressBar health indicator, etc.
This scene would then have attached a script defining the base instance of an enemy. Something like:
# baseEnemy.gd

class_name baseEnemy
extends WhateverNodeTypeYouWantToExtend

@export var enemy_name : String = "Placeholder Enemy!"

@export var hp : int = 01
@export var hpMax : int = 01

func _ready():
    $label.text = "%s" % enemy_name 
    $healthBar.min_value = 0
    $healthBar.max_value = hpMax
    $healthBar.value = hp

func generic_behavior():
    # Placeholder generic behavior. Something that is shared!
    # For example, a function like lower_health() might apply to every enemy type
    pass

func specific_behavior():
    # Placeholder specific behavior. Something that will be overridden!
    # For example, a function like decide_next_action() might be different for every class
    pass

Now, we have set ourselves up to create subclasses. We would then define many subclasses, in the style of:
# enemyA.gd

class_name enemyA
extends baseEnemy

enemy_name = "Enemy A!"
hpMax = 100

func _ready():
    # This time, whatever paramters we want will be changed for enemies of this class.
    # for example, changing the name, hp, etc.
    # This next line means to call _ready as defined by its superclass, which is baseEnemy
    super._ready()

func specific_behavior():
    # Now we would define this function, and this code will only be run for enemies of this type!
    pass

But we still have the problem of actually instancing the subclass.
Let's say we have some scene where we want an enemyA to exist in. We would do:
# script for main scene.
var enemy_scene = preload("res://path/to/baseEnemy.tscn")

func _ready():
    spawn_enemy("A")

func spawn_enemyA(s):
    
    var enemy_instance = enemy_scene.instantiate()
    # This line is where you would add logic to decide what script to attach
    var enemy_script
    if s=="A":
        # make sure to load script first.
        enemy_script = load("res://path/to/enemyA.gd")
        enemy_instance.set_script(enemy_script)
    else:
        print("invalid type")

    # Add the enemy instance to the scene tree
    add_child(enemy_instance)

    # force a ready call, in case
    enemy_instance._ready()

And now, the object spawns with name "Enemy A", correct hp, and uses the specified version of specific_behavior().
